# Difference between "site:current-user:field-foo" and "account:field-foo" in setting a Rules condition?

Tags: rules, tokens

What is the difference between "site:current-user:field-foo" and "account:field-foo" in the Rules "Add a new condition"?

Comment: It depends on the context of the rule...what event are you responding to?

Comment: that's "After saving a new user account"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments the variables you have available to you in a rule depend on the context it's in.

`[site:current-user]` is a global token available to any rule and will always return an object relating to the currently logged in user.

The `[account]` token is there because you're responding to the "After saving a new user account" event; that event passes an object relating to the user object that has just been saved (for obvious reasons).

I guess the main distinction is that the former will always give the currently logged in user, while the latter could be a different user object altogether (if, for example, an administrator had created the account).

Answer (score 1):

In the "After saving a new user account" event, [account:field-foo] is referring to the account being saved, while [site:current-user:field-foo] is referring to the currently logged-in user, which possibly is the user who created the new account, or caused the account to be automatically created.

In the case of an administrator creating an account for another user, [site:current-user:field-foo] would be for the administrator account.